# Aggregate over multiple list in subfield with multiple aggregation operators

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I have a collection of documents with the following structure:

```
{'_id': 'xxx',
 'name': 'some_name',
 'data': {
     'first_thing': [1, 2, 3, 4],
     'second_thing': [5, 3, 2, 4],
     }
}
```

My goal is to compute the mean and standard deviation over the values of each subfield under 'data'. I tried the following to query a single subfield:

```
cursor = db.testcoll.aggregate([
    {
        '$project': {
            '_id': '$name',
            'data.first_thing.mean': {'$avg': '$data.first_thing'},
            'data.first_thing.std': {'$stdDevPop': '$data.first_thing'}
        }
    }
])
```

In the result, the field 'data' is a list, in which the aggregations `$avg`, and `$stdDevPop` are repeated for each element in the original list 'first_thing':

```
{'data': {
    'first_thing': [
       {'mean': 2.5, 'std': 1.118033988749895},
       {'mean': 2.5, 'std': 1.118033988749895},
       {'mean': 2.5, 'std': 1.118033988749895},
       {'mean': 2.5, 'std': 1.118033988749895}]},
 '_id': 'some_name'
}
```

Obviously, I need the aggregations only once, that is:

```
{'data': {
    'first_thing': {
        'mean': 2.5,
        'std': 1.118033988749895
     },
 '_id': 'some_name'
}
```

I observed that when I change the name of the result field to something else than the name of the original field, the aggregation is performed only once. So, the query:

```
cursor = db.testcoll.aggregate([
    {
        '$project': {
            '_id': '$name',
            'data.some_thing.mean': {'$avg': '$data.first_thing'},
            'data.some_thing.std': {'$stdDevPop': '$data.first_thing'}
        }
    }
])
```

gives me what I want. However, in the resulting document, the aggregations of 'first_thing' are in a subfield called 'some_thing'.

How do I have to change the query such that the result is:

```
{'data': {
    'first_thing': {
        'mean': 2.5, 
        'std': 1.118033988749895},
 '_id': 'some_name'
}
```

?

I further observed that removing the 'data.' part in the naming of the result field, like

```
cursor = db.testcoll.aggregate([
    {
       ...
       'first_thing.mean': {'$avg': '$data.first_thing'},
       ...
        }}])
```

the result is as expected; with the only drawback that all "things" are at the top level of the result document. However, I need them to be in a subfield.

Answer (score 0):

`data.first_thing` is an array, so you set the value for each item in this array.

Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "data.mean": { "$avg": "$data.first_thing" },
      "data.std": { "$stdDevPop": "$data.first_thing" }
    }
  },
  { "$set": { "data.first_thing": null } },
  {
    "$project": {
      "data.first_thing.mean": "$data.mean",
      "data.first_thing.std": "$data.std",
      "_id": "$name",
      
    }
  }
])
```

or this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "data.first_thing.mean": { "$avg": "$data.first_thing" },
      "data.first_thing.std": { "$stdDevPop": "$data.first_thing" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "data.first_thing": { $setUnion: "$data.first_thing" },
      "_id": "$name"
    }
  }
])
```

Using `$unwind` and `$group` afterwards seems to be an overkill in my opinion.

Comment: This does not work. Both of your proposals give different results that do not match my desired result.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because `first_thing` is an array. You can do multiple ways to achieve your target.

1. One way to `unwind` to flat the array and group it.

Code is given below

```
[
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": "$name",
      "data.first_thing.mean": {
        "$avg": "$data.first_thing"
      },
      "data.first_thing.std": {
        "$stdDevPop": "$data.first_thing"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$data.first_thing"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      data: {
        $addToSet: {
          first_thing: [
            "$data.first_thing"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jTC7UFlIUqv)

2. You can have the mean and std in different variable, and put it inside the array

Code is given below

```
 [
      {
        "$project": {
          "_id": "$name",
          "mean": {
            "$avg": "$data.first_thing"
          },
          "std": {
            "$stdDevPop": "$data.first_thing"
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          "data.first_thing": [
            {
              mean: "$mean",
              std: "$std"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Working[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VROw8RSlYT6)

Comment: The resulting doc has 'std' and 'mean' under 'first_thing' and one more time at the top level.

Comment: you can remove it with `$project`. https://mongoplayground.net/p/Akh33NJa3PI

Comment: This answer does not help me, because both of your attempts do not match my desired result.